# creating a 2d array using double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i have made a program that creates 2d array.
the code below works well on visual studio & turbo c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int **allocarr(int **arr, int row, int col){
    int i;
    arr=calloc(row, sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        arr[i]=calloc(col, sizeof(int));


    }

    return arr;
}

void freearr(int **arr, int row, int col){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<row; i++) free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);


}

void printarr(int **arr, int row, int col){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("\t%d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }


}



int main(){
    int **arr=NULL;
    arr=allocarr(arr, 3, 3);
    arr[2][2]=8;
    printarr(arr, 3, 3);
    freearr(arr,3, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

but it does not work on mac os x gcc and mingw gcc.
everything compiles fine without any warning and errors(-Wall & -Wextra),
but it crashes on runtime...
in gdb and lldb, it says that `free()` is freeing a non-allocated memory.

after allocating a pointer array, when i allocate memory after that, exactly 2 of the memory block(is this the right word?) will have random values that cannot be initialized.

i tried allocating another array before i assign it to the pointer array.
it prints fine(no 2 random values), but will still occasionally crash when assigning values on it.
why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
arr=(int **)calloc(row, sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
arr = calloc(row, sizeof(int*));
```

(note that the cast is not required in C [and actually discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

So on implementations where the size of a pointer is not the size of `int` (e.g. on x64 machines), you will invoke undefined behavior when you read outside the bounds of allocated memory.

You might consider not using an explicit type as the operand of `sizeof`.

```
arr = calloc(row, sizeof*arr);
```

This lets the compiler deduce the type and will help you avoid errors like this.

Comment: i know that. but it still doesnt change the fact that its not working.

Comment: @hoholee12 It works fine on my side, no leaks detected

Comment: @PC Luddite examples please. where can i find the UB in the code?

Comment: @hoholee12I think this should correct the error. Are you sure you changed `sizeof(int)` to `sizeof(int*)`?

Comment: @hoholee12 Anytime you read or write to the upper-indices of `arr`, you will invoke undefined behavior. You haven't allocated enough memory in `arr` to store all `int*` when `sizeof(int*) > sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @PCLuddite ah, didn't notice the sizeof(int*). thanks.